# web API calling not return response from controller in Aurelia JS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, aurelia

I'm calling web API controller from Aurelia JS but i'm not getting any response from web API controller.

here is my code :

```
httpClient.fetch('/api/controllername', {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(passvaluetocontroller)
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  alert(data);
  alert("success");
});
```

here is my controller code :

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(passvaluetocontroller s)
{
  return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

so I am not getting any response and also it is showing error in console:
`Uncaught` (in promise)
SyntaxError:

> Unexpected end of JSON input.

How can I do work when the request is successful?

Comment: You might be getting a response, but it's not valid JSON. This is usually a sign that the server is returning an error of some kind. What do you see in the network tab of your browser tools?

Comment: With errors like this I find Fiddler an invaluable tool. Use it to check you post data and the server response.

Answer (score 3):

The cause is very simple. You are not actually sending anything from your controller method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(passvaluetocontroller s)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

By passing the `HttpResponseMessage` method a `System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted`, you are creating a response whose header contains the `Accepted` status code, but its **body** is empty. Therefore, there is nothing to deserialize. The `response.json()` will fail if the response is empty, that's why you are getting the error.

There are 2 possible solutions:

- If you do not even intend to send any actual content back from the server, then simply don't call `response.json()` since there is nothing that you need in it. In that case, in your `.then(...)` method, simply check for `response.ok`. Doing this will tell you whether the response represents a successful operation - that is, the response status code is `2xx`.
- If you actually want to deserialize something, then simply send something from the server to deserialize. You can do that like this:

```
public object Post(passvaluetocontroller s)
{
    return new { Test = "Test" };
}
```

Obviously, you can change the `object` return type to whatever you want and so can you return an object of your liking from within the action method.